# Awk does not recognize fields as integer values

Tags: bash, awk, filter

I'm trying to filter one file based on two columns of another one.
The problem is that `awk` is not differentiating, for example, this interval 70083 83083, from position 7323573 (please see below).
The aim is to retrieve the value for file 1 that is in the column 5 of file 2.
File 1 has only one position in the column 3 ex: 51476, and the file 2 has an interval represented by column 3 and 4. 
In the end I need the file 1 with respective values of the column 5 (see output).

file 1

```
rs187298206 chr1 51476 0.0072 0.201426626822702
rs116400033 chr1 51479 0.2055 1.18445621536109
rs62637813 chr1 52058 0.0587 0.551216300225955
rs190291950 chr1 52144 -4e-04 0.036575951491895
rs150021059 chr1 52238 0.3325 1.70427928591544
rs140052487 chr1 54353 0.003 0.12778378962414
rs146477069 chr1 54421 0.1419 0.924336309646664
rs141149254 chr1 54490 0.1767 1.06786868821145
rs2462492 chr1 54676 0.0819 0.664355314594874
rs143174675 chr1 54753 0.026 0.356836206987615
rs3091274 chr1 55164 0.3548 1.80091078751368
rs10399749 chr1 55299 0.0309 0.389748348495465
rs182462964 chr1 55313 2e-04 0.0877969207975495
rs3107975 chr1 55326 0.0237 0.344080010917931
rs142800240 chr1 7323573 -6e-04 0.0361473609720785
```

file 2

```
51083_1 chr1 51083 56000 -0.177152387075888 0.172569306719619
57083_1 chr1 57083 60083 -0.0524335467819781 0.130497858911419
60083_1 chr1 70083 83083 -0.0332555672564894 0.124932838766226
525083_1 chr1 525083 528083 0.291406335374442 0.0577249392691202
528083_1 chr1 528083 531083 0.291406335374442 0.0577249392691202
531083_1 chr1 531083 534083 0.291406335374442 0.0577249392691202
534083_1 chr1 534083 537083 0.291406335374442 0.0577249392691202
534083_1 chr1 534083 537083 0.441406335374442 0.0577249392691202
```

What I get with this script:

```
awk '
NR == FNR {score[$3] = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4; next}
{
for (key in score)
if (key > $3 && key < $4)
print score[key], $5
}
' file1 file2 > output
```

output

```
 rs140052487 chr1 54353 0.003 -0.177152387075888
 rs150021059 chr1 52238 0.3325 -0.177152387075888
 rs3107975 chr1 55326 0.0237 -0.177152387075888
 rs3091274 chr1 55164 0.3548 -0.177152387075888
 rs187298206 chr1 51476 0.0072 -0.177152387075888
 rs116400033 chr1 51479 0.2055 -0.177152387075888
 rs10399749 chr1 55299 0.0309 -0.177152387075888
 rs146477069 chr1 54421 0.1419 -0.177152387075888
 rs190291950 chr1 52144 -4e-04 -0.177152387075888
 rs182462964 chr1 55313 2e-04 -0.177152387075888
 rs141149254 chr1 54490 0.1767 -0.177152387075888
 rs62637813 chr1 52058 0.0587 -0.177152387075888
 rs143174675 chr1 54753 0.026 -0.177152387075888
 rs2462492 chr1 54676 0.0819 -0.177152387075888
 rs142800240 chr1 7323573 -6e-04 -0.0332555672564894 <- this should not appear
```

Comment: How are `fst.txt` and `tajima.txt` related to the `file 1` and `file 2` in your example? Explain what you mean by `filter`, i.e. in what way fields of one file should be related to fields in the other file in order to produce output. Tell us WHY the line you have indicated should not appear. Don't answer in a comment - edit your question instead.

Comment: thanks Morton, I changed already ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '     
NR == FNR {score[$3] = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4; next}
{
for (key in score)
if (key+0 > $3 && key+0 < $4)
print score[key], $5
}
' fst.txt tajima.txt > output
```

gives me

```
[/tmp]$ cat output
rs182462964 chr1 55313 2e-04 -0.177152387075888
rs190291950 chr1 52144 -4e-04 -0.177152387075888
rs62637813 chr1 52058 0.0587 -0.177152387075888
rs146477069 chr1 54421 0.1419 -0.177152387075888
rs140052487 chr1 54353 0.003 -0.177152387075888
rs3107975 chr1 55326 0.0237 -0.177152387075888
rs187298206 chr1 51476 0.0072 -0.177152387075888
rs141149254 chr1 54490 0.1767 -0.177152387075888
rs10399749 chr1 55299 0.0309 -0.177152387075888
rs3091274 chr1 55164 0.3548 -0.177152387075888
rs143174675 chr1 54753 0.026 -0.177152387075888
rs2462492 chr1 54676 0.0819 -0.177152387075888
rs150021059 chr1 52238 0.3325 -0.177152387075888
rs116400033 chr1 51479 0.2055 -0.177152387075888
```

to force the interpretation as a number, add 0 to it.  from the man page for awk.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your problem on Mac OS X 10.11.3 with the system's BSD `awk`.

The problem is to do with string vs number comparison; `awk` appears to be treating the `key` as a string and is doing a string comparison rather than a numerical comparison.

I've brute-forced it into treating the comparison numerically with:

```
awk '
NR == FNR {score[$3] = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4; next}
{
    for (key in score)
    {
        if (key+0 > $3+0 && key+0 < $4+0)
        {
            #print "==", key, $3, $4
            #if (key > $3) print key, ">", $3
            #if (key < $4) print key, "<", $4
            print score[key], $5
        }
    }
}
' file1 file2
```

You can see the '`+0`' to force `awk` to treat things as numbers. (The analogue to force `awk` to treat a value as a string is, for example, `key ""`, which concatenates an empty string to the (string) value of `key`.)

With your sample data, I then get the output:

```
rs140052487 chr1 54353 0.003 -0.177152387075888
rs150021059 chr1 52238 0.3325 -0.177152387075888
rs3107975 chr1 55326 0.0237 -0.177152387075888
rs3091274 chr1 55164 0.3548 -0.177152387075888
rs187298206 chr1 51476 0.0072 -0.177152387075888
rs116400033 chr1 51479 0.2055 -0.177152387075888
rs10399749 chr1 55299 0.0309 -0.177152387075888
rs146477069 chr1 54421 0.1419 -0.177152387075888
rs190291950 chr1 52144 -4e-04 -0.177152387075888
rs182462964 chr1 55313 2e-04 -0.177152387075888
rs141149254 chr1 54490 0.1767 -0.177152387075888
rs62637813 chr1 52058 0.0587 -0.177152387075888
rs143174675 chr1 54753 0.026 -0.177152387075888
rs2462492 chr1 54676 0.0819 -0.177152387075888
```

Part of the debugging output, which gave the game away, was:

```
== 54676 51083 56000
54676 > 51083
54676 < 56000
rs2462492 chr1 54676 0.0819 -0.177152387075888
== 7323573 70083 83083
7323573 > 70083
7323573 < 83083
rs142800240 chr1 7323573 -6e-04 -0.0332555672564894
```

For the 5-digit strings, the comparison happened to work the same as a numeric comparison.  For the other, it did not.  I should also point out that the `$3+0` and `$4+0` parts are probably not essential.  I had those when I got the debugging output shown — but the tests only started to work when I added `0` to the `key`.  I probably don't need to add the `0` to `$3` or `$4`, therefore.

Comment: wrt `awk appears to be treating the key as a string` - the key IS a string because it's an array index and all array indices are strings. You're correct that you don't need to add 0 to $3 or $4.

Comment: @EdMorton:  That makes sense. There's a bit more to it than that — even when you coerce the `$3` and `$4` to numbers, the stringiness of `key` forces the comparison back to a string comparison, which surprised me.  Forcing the `key` to a number is crucial — then the `$3` or `$4` is also treated as a number. I'm not sure if it is a LHS vs RHS issue; at one level, I don't care, but at another, I do. It is probably documented somewhere (POSIX [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)
for example, or [GNU `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

Comment: Thanks guys! For solving the problem and for the explanation about the awk interpretation =)

Comment: Hmmm, GNU's [Strings and Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strings-And-Numbers) section only says "if the context of the `awk` program demands it", without elucidating such fine detail as why `if (key > $3+0)` doesn't demand a numeric operation.  The POSIX text on 'Expressions in awk' covers a lot of material but still doesn't seem to cover whether `a < b` the comparison will be a string comparison or a numeric comparison when the LHS operand is a string and the RHS operand is a number.  It does state that `$3` shall be treated as a number if it can be (and it can).

Comment: @CalvinTaylor no, key started out as string because it's an array index. Jonathan - all variables in awk are of type numeric-string unless you do something to tell awk they ARE specifically numeric or specifically string. key IS specifically string and when you add 0 to $3 the RHS becomes specifically numeric so there is no obvious type of comparison to use so per the comparison table at http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Typing-and-Comparison if you compare a string with any type (string, numeric, or numeric-string) a string comparison is used.

Comment: On the other hand, $3 is a numeric-string so when you convert key to numeric by adding zero, you get a numeric being compared to a numeric-string and so numeric comparison is used.